# How to create the file format in Snowflake?

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have below sample csv data with column delimiter as "|" and row delimiter is "|\n". I am receiving below error. How can I create the File Format?

```
Key|DimType|IntCo|Flg|InsertDateTime|UpdateDateTime|rwSts|
1|1||0|2021-12-05 03:16:54Z|2021-12-05 03:16:54Z|NDT|
2|2|QUNDTVRSWFBLVDE=|0|2021-12-05 03:16:54Z|2021-12-05 03:16:54Z|NDT|
```

Sample command used:

```
create or replace file format my_pipe_format_new
                                  type = csv
                                  skip_header = 1
                                  skip_blank_lines = true
                                  field_delimiter  = '|'
                                  record_delimiter  = '|\r\n'
                                  empty_field_as_null= true;
```

[image]

Comment: that is rather mis-produced data, because a line should be delimetered with the same values as the columns. Anyways, remove the pipe from the line, and just select 1 to n-1 columns of the input, as the last will always be empty.

Comment: You could just slip an empty NULL field into the last spot in your SELECT clause and change the record_delimiter to `/r/n` without the pipe. --just saw the date on this question. Likely you've figured this out by now. @halfer is in here editing old questions.

Comment: Yup @JNevill, all questions are subject to improvement 